# In JavaScript/jQuery, how to retrieve data that has spaces in its name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am retrieving JSON using jQuery's getJSON call.

My problem is that some of the fields in the returned JSON have spaces in them.

How do I retrieve these values from the JSON without changing the source data? See line marked "ERROR" below:

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function(objData) {
  $.each(objData.data, function(i, item) {
    var zip = item.Zip;
    var fname = item.First Name; //ERROR
  });
});
```

Example JSON:

```
jsonp123456789({"data":[{"Zip":"12345","First Name":"Bob"},{"Zip":"23456","First Name":"Joe"},{"Zip":"34567","First Name":"Bill"}]})
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is there a space in the JSON name if you want to use it as a Javascript Object?

Comment: Spaces are allowed in identifiers, awkward but allowed.

Comment: I know you can do it. The question is why not just use FirstName so you can use the nice clean dot syntax.

Comment: In my case, the JSON data is provided by a 3rd party. If I controlled the data, I would probably use FirstName.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Array member access notation works on objects as well.

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function(objData) {
  $.each(objData.data, function(i, item) {
    var zip = item.Zip;
    var fname = item['First Name'];
  });
});
```

You can use this for arbitrary strings (those that aren't legal identifiers) as well as variables.

```
var fieldName = "First Name";
var fname = item[fieldName];
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function(objData) {
  $.each(objData.data, function(i, item) {
    var zip = item.Zip;
    var fname = item["First Name"]; //Changed this
  });
});
```

reference the item using as a key instead of dot notation